# python fabric to fail in parallel run

Tags: python, chef-infra, fabric

I'm running chef-client with python fabric, in parallel mode and I want it to fail if one of the chef runs is failing.

The `warn_only=False` should do it as I understand but no exception is throwing for stopping the run.
What else can I do?

Comment: How do you know if a run fails?  warn_only and error handling triggers on the status code of the previous run.  Is there any additional output that you can use to determine failure / success?